# Cannot use Direct Query Data Set on Power BI online

Tags: powerbi, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to use the Direct Query feature in Power BI

It is working on Power BI Desktop, but when I publish it to Power BI online, it gives the error below.

The source database is Azure SQL Database with pricing tier Standard S0: 10 DTUs.

The Power BI license is Premium (I've also tried with Pro).

The firewall setting of the Azure SQL Database
[image: firewall setting of the Azure SQL Database]

**The error:**

```
Cannot load model

Couldn't load the model schema associated with this report. Make sure you have a connection to the server, and try again.
Please try again later or contact support. If you contact support, please provide these details.

Activity ID671fca94-b76e-4660-a944-dff3b06235b3
Request ID748c1fb6-d8c1-b1af-072a-ea49a79c6b64
Correlation ID862117fb-f595-4130-40be-f1d195fa7cbe
TimeSat Sep 18 2021 18:13:33 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
Service version13.0.16736.54
Client version2108.5.07549-train
Cluster URIhttps://wabi-europe-north-b-redirect.analysis.windows.net/
```

[image: Power BI error]

Comment: What tier is your database? Is it possibly serverless tier and has auto-paused so there is a connection failure while it auto-resumes?

Comment: @GregGalloway The pricing tier for the database is: Standard S0: 10 DTUs

Comment: And what credentials do you have in the dataset? Have you checked in the power bi server if the credentials are saved correctly?

Comment: @JoaoLeal What do you mean by "power bi server"?

Answer (score 1):

When you are using Azure SQL Database as a data source, you must provide credentials before the Power BI service shows the published report.

Follow the instructions to provide the credentials from this [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-use-directquery#publish-to-the-power-bi-service).

> If credentials are not added error occurs when opening the published report or a dataset that is created with the DirectQuery connection.

Comment: Thanks. However, I've already done that and it still isn't working.